# Multiple Reactive FormGroups for a single data source

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My data source looks something like this:

```
data = {
  Bob:   {
           hobbies: ['cycling', 'swimming'],
           pets: ['cat', 'dog']
         },
  Alice: {
           hobbies: ['cycling, 'chess'],
           pets: ['fish', 'dog']
         }
}
```

My need is to create a multi-select for each user, hobby, and pet.

E.g.
Bob and Alice each have two multi-selects, one for hobbies, and one for pets.
Cycling has a multi-select for associated users (it would have both Bob and Alice as selected).
Cat has a multi-select for associated users (it would have Bob as selected, and Alice as unselected).

The issue I'm having is how to handle a selection/de-selection of a user on the Cat multi-select and its effect on that user's Pet's multi-select.

I currently am deriving byUser, byPet, and byHobby objects from my datasource and then generating three distinct FormGroups from those objects. The problem is that I now have three separate data sources. I'd like to have changes in one form group apply changes to the others so that the data stays in sync.

Is there a more elegant solution where I can somehow use a single FormGroup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter option from data while selecting data from one dropdown